# How to fix error 1406 when importing a dumpfile

Tags: mysql

I use `MySQLdump.exe` to create a dumpfile `dumpfile.sql`. When importing this file using

`mysql -u user -p test < dumpfile.sql`

I run into

> error 1406: data too long for column1 'mailto' at row 1.

The value that should be inserted is max. 50 characters, field definition is char(50)". This field can contain all letters, numbers and characters like ";" and spaces.

Further testing shows it has something to do with "special" characters, like "é". The database has characterset latin1 --cp1252 West European.

How come that MySQL cannot import the backupfile it just created?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you searched for that line in question?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the column size

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name MODIFY email VARCHAR(255) ;
```

or you could try importing your dump in a temporary database or table and the perform a insert select reducing the size where you need in the real  database or table (obviolsy in this way you are at risk for loss content information)

Comment: I know, but the database fieldsize is equal (and fixed length) for all users. I cannot allow changes in fieldsize, as backups from various customers would have different field sizes. I just have to find a way to allow a value of 50 characters to be restored in a 50 character  field without changing the basic tables.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it's becoming quite complicated to automate that task for our users. The database has many tables and with information loss I'm probably out of business.

Comment: I discovered now that when I add "SET NAMES UTF8;" in the header of my backup file it works. So far so good!